# Where can I still find solar film?

Tags: the-sun, telescope, amateur-observing, solar-eclipse, resource-request

I, like many others, am excited to see the eclipse. I want to view the eclipse through my telescope, however, I don't have any solar safety equipment for solar viewing and I cannot find any online that I can get before the eclipse. Could anyone lead me to a reputable site where I could purchase solar (preferably mylar) film before the eclipse?

Comment: I gotta say I don't think any vendor would be able to get you the shipment in time, unless they do weekend shipping.

Comment: I would realise advise against any viewing of the Sun through a telescope, safety equipment or not. Use a projection.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon has solar film sheets if that's what you're looking for. It is sold by Amazon for [Thousand Oaks Optical](http://thousandoaksoptical.com/products/solar-filters/). Amazon sometimes has next day or 2 days delivery.

Answer (score -2):

If you know somebody who still owns [floppy disks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floppy_disk), you might consider recycling their inside as filter. Please test before relying on them for protecting your eyes. I did use them during the last solar eclipse as filter for my analog camera with reasonable results.

#### References

- https://www.instructables.com/Floppy-Disk-Sun-Filter/

Comment: [Not recommended](https://mreclipse.com/Special/filters.html#safety) by optometrist Ralph Chou.

Comment: @MikeG I adjusted a bit the wording, thanks for your hint.